# How to iterate over two lists in a specific order

Tags: python, for-loop

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['A','C','E','G','A']
list2 = ['B','D','F','H','N']
```

I would like to create these new names and append them to an empty list

```
A_vs_B
C_vs_D
E_vs_F
G_vs_H
A_vs_N
```

The structure is, the 1st item in list1 with 1st item in list 2 and so on. I only want these names.

This is what I've done so far

```
newlist = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list 2:
        name = i + '_vs_' + j
        newlist.append(name)
```

The problem with this it creates every possible combination of names between list1
& list2. How do I limit my loop to only produce names I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), which takes two lists (or other iterables) and creates an iterable of tuples. In the for loop unpack the tuple to the variables `i` and `j`

```py
newlist = []
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    name = i + '_vs_' + j
    newlist.append(name)
```

You could further improve your code using format-strings:

```py
newlist = []
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    newlist.append(f'{i}_vs_{j}')
```

and using list-comprehensions:

```py
newlist = [f'{i}_vs_{j}' for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
list1 = ['A','C','E','G','A']
list2 = ['B','D','F','H','N']

newlist = []

for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    name = list1[i] + '_vs_' + list2[i]
    newlist.append(name)
print(newlist)
```

Comment: TY so much for taking time to answer